# Android GZIPInputStream not recognizing gzip format

Tags: php, android, gzip

This has really been annoying me and it is quite important for me to find the problem here.
The android code below is not unzipping for me.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www**************/get.php");
        get.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        try {                   
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            //Log msg header
            Header[] header = response.getAllHeaders();
            for(Header i : header) {
                Log.d("TEST", i.getName() + ":" + i.getValue() );
            }
            if (contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Content is gzipped");
                try {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                    processStream(instream);
                 } finally {
                     instream.close();
                 }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Logcat output:

```
D/TEST    ( 1067): Date:Fri, 03 Jun 2011 05:18:33 GMT
D/TEST    ( 1067): Server:Apache
D/TEST    ( 1067): X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.10
D/TEST    ( 1067): Content-Encoding:gzip
D/TEST    ( 1067): Content-Length:765
D/TEST    ( 1067): Connection:close
D/TEST    ( 1067): Content-Type:application/json
D/TEST    ( 1067): Content is gzipped

W/System.err( 1067): java.io.IOException: Unknown format
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:85)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:66)
W/System.err( 1067):    at com.mannotron.gallery.GalleryExample$GetImages.doInBackground(GalleryExample.java:69)
W/System.err( 1067):    at com.mannotron.gallery.GalleryExample$GetImages.doInBackground(GalleryExample.java:1)
W/System.err( 1067):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
W/System.err( 1067):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

edit: added php code

Server side php:

```
//ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
header("Content-Encoding: gzip"); 


$dbhost = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";
$user = "xxxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxxx";

//Open databse connection
$db = new mysqli($dbhost,$user,$pass,$dbname) or die('Error opening db');   


$query = "SELECT * FROM Spots; ";
$result = null;
$result = $db->query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data [] = $row;
}
$spots = '{"spots":'.json_encode($data)."}";
echo gzencode($spots,FORCE_GZIP);

$db->close();   
//ob_flush();
```

?>

I have tried both gz_encode() and outputbuffering with gzip at the server end in php. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you show the first few bytes of instream on the client´s side?

Comment: The stream comes in as [a,1f,8b,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,bd,96,....]

Is that what you meant?

The characterset from a BufferedReader looks like:

D/TEST    ( 1275): ▼´┐└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç└Ç♥´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢n´┐¢0►´┐¢_e´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢I´┐¢8!´┐¢Ë╗¶´┐¢A

Comment: Yep. And the first 'a' is wrong. A gzipped file/stream should start with '1f8b'. Do you by chance have a stray „a“ in your php-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream looks wrong, as it should start with '1f8b'. The reason might be a stray 'a' in your php-file. But the posted samples seem to be  all right.

Comment: hmmm a in ascii seems to be a newline, do you now how that could get in? The php is exactly what I've put up (with only <?php before the code block i posted). Thanks alot for the help i'm just about there now. :D